# Allowing mimes in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Short question:**

Is there anything more I need to do to allow file extensions in my MVC application than to edit my Web.config? The following does not work:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cch" mimeType="application/unknown" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cc1" mimeType="application/unknown" />
</staticContent>
<handlers>
  ...
</handlers>
```

[Link to picture of error page](http://img.xrmb2.net/images/585560.png)

**Long question (details):**

The most important details is that the code above **works** in a non-mvc ASP .NET web application, so there is something in MVC that prevents this (this is also what the high-rated answers says in other questions I have found). I also know the path is correct, as I can access picture files in the same folder as the files (.cch, .cc1) are located.

I have used a software (Fusion 2.5) to create an application that shall work with HTML5. When you export the application, you get an index.html, a javascript file, picture files with all the graphics, a .cch file and a .cc1 file.

[Picture of my project in Visual Studio](http://img.xrmb2.net/images/736319.png)

If you can see the index.html page, this is the file I am trying out on. Obviously, this is not the right way to do things in MVC, but the site do opens, and displays a 404 not found on the .cch file (if I click on this, I get the error page I linked first). For the record, I have also tried to move the content of index.html into a layout file, but I get the same errors here. Accessing the .png files works just fine.

Code where the .cch file is used:

```
<script src="src-right/Runtime.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);
    function windowLoaded()
    {
        new Runtime("MMFCanvas", "resources-right/right.cch");
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea whats going on?

**EDIT:**

I solved this by doing something I should have done a long time ago: starting a new MVC project. I am clueless about what the actual issue was, but comparing the two web.config files in my old and new projects, I see they are totally different. The issue-MVC project was also my first project on this PC, and during this I did a lot of things like fixing connections to Azure, etc. Maybe, somewhere on the way, something went wrong.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Can you confirm that the path created by `new Runtime("MMFCanvas", "resources-right/right.cch");` is the right one?

Comment: Yes, this should be correct. Chrome shows a 404 error on the path to the cch file, but if I try any of the pictures in the same folder, its working.

Comment: Didn't see the error page, my bad. Check my answer

Comment: Can you check if the mimetype was added in IIS?

Comment: Try to remove it first in your web.config: <remove fileExtension=".cch" />

Comment: @Leandro Soares: Tried, did not help :(
I have also published it on azurewebsites (for what its worth), and it gives the same error.

Comment: @jpgrassi tried this aswell, but did not work..

Answer (score 1):

I bet 404 is the response your server is returning because the MIME type is not set in the server.

Go to IIS configuration and add the mime type there.

Comment: It was not there, but adding it did not help :(

Comment: There are some extensions that are blocked by IIS (for security reasons), .mdb is one of them for example, maybe those you're trying to use are also?

Comment: More on "request filtering" https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The problem was an unknown issue with my project. A fresh MVC did the trick, for some annoying reason..

Answer (score 0):

Use mimetype `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/unknown`.

The "octet-stream" subtype is used to indicate that a body contains arbitrary binary data.

Comment: I was just about to edit this in.. I have also already tried this, and it is not working.